# Hive - OR condition with left outer join

Tags: hadoop, hive, union, outer-join

I have referred all the queries on SO for a similar case. Although the error may be common, I am looking for solution for the specific case. Please refrain from marking the question duplicate, unless you get exactly the same scenario with an accepted solution.

---

I have two tables

```
Main table:

c1  c2  c3  c4  c5
1   2   3   4   A

Other table

c1  c2  c3  c4  c5
1   8   5   6   B
8   2   8   9   C
8   7   3   9   C
8   7   9   4   C
5   6   7   8   D
```

Now, from the other table, I should only be able to pick only unique record across all the column. e.g. the last row (`5,6,7,8, D`) only.

Row 1 from other table rejected, because c1 value (1) is same as c1 value (1) in main table, Row 2 rejected because c2 value of other and main table matches and likewise...

In a nutshell, none of the columns from other table should have the same value (in corresponding column) in main table in the output of the query.

---

I tried creating below query

```
select t1.* from otherTable t1
LEFT OUTER JOIN mainTable t2
ON ( t1.c1 = t2.c1 OR t1.c2 = t2.c2 OR t1.c3 = t2.c3 OR t1.c4 = t2.c4 )
Where t2.c5 is null;
```

However, hive throws below exception

> OR not supported in JOIN currently

I understand the hive limitation and many time I have used `UNION (ALL | DISTINCT)` with inner join to overcome this limitation; but not able to use the same strategy with this.

Please help.

**EDIT 1** : I have hive version restriction - Can only use version 1.2.0

Comment: "pick only unique record across all the column" is a fragment of unclear language. "none of the columns from [the] other table should have the same value (in [the] corresponding column) in [the] main table" is clear. (Hence it's not "in a nutshell", which means unclear & pithy but hopefully helpful for grasping or remembering *some other description* that is *clear*. Please take the time to write what you mean so that someone who does not already know what you mean will know. Like us. When you say it clearly you don't have to say it (fuzzily) again.

Answer (score 0):

You can do cartesian product join (an inner join with no conditions):

```
select t1.* from otherTable t1
,mainTable t2
WHERE  t1.c1 != t2.c1 AND t1.c2 != t2.c2 
       AND t1.c3 != t2.c3 AND t1.c4 != t2.c4 AND t1.c5 !=  t2.c5;
```

Assuming you have one row in the `mainTable` this query should be as efficient as one that uses `OUTER JOIN`

Another option is to break your proposed query into 5 different `LEFT OUTER JOIN` sub-queries:

```
select t1.* from (
  select t1.* from (
    select t1.* from (
      select t1.* from (
        select t1.* from otherTable t1
        LEFT OUTER JOIN (select distinct c1 from mainTable) t2
        ON ( t1.c1 = t2.c1) Where t2.c1 is null ) t1
      LEFT OUTER JOIN (select distinct c2 from mainTable) t2
      ON ( t1.c2 = t2.c2) Where t2.c2 is null ) t1
    LEFT OUTER JOIN (select distinct c3 from mainTable) t2
    ON ( t1.c3 = t2.c3) Where t2.c3 is null ) t1
  LEFT OUTER JOIN (select distinct c4 from mainTable) t2
  ON ( t1.c4 = t2.c4) Where t2.c4 is null ) t1
LEFT OUTER JOIN (select distinct c5 from mainTable) t2
ON ( t1.c5 = t2.c5) Where t2.c5 is null
;
```

Here, for each column, I first get the distinct columns from the `mainTable` and join it with what's left of `otherTable`. The downside is that I pass 5 times over `mainTable` - once for each column. If the values in main table are unique, you can remove the `distinct` from the subqueries.

Comment: Since Hive is a warehouse, so assume that it would have TBs of data and an inner join without a condition is not a viable option. If this is the only solution, then better I should write a Map-Reduce program to process the data and re-create a hive table on output.

Comment: @gyan An inner/cross version is the obvious expression of what you want. inner join on & cross join where mean the same thing. Even Hive knows that. Why are you afraid of inner/cross join? Outer join is just inner/cross join that also adds unmatched left table rows extended by nulls. You are *already* expecting Hive to know how to optimize where with joins.

Comment: I am not worried about inner join [with a join condition], it simply does not solve this specific case. Kindly help me framing the query, if I am not getting it. A cross join is not viable, because the main table is having 970 Mn (~5 TB) records and the other table is having 1.5 Bn records (~ 7 TB) and we have a time window to process them. If hive 1.2.0 is not having an optimal solution, Hive UDF or MR remains only option.

Comment: @gyan added a possible solution, it might work in your time window.